# How do I create a method for listeners?

Tags: android, kotlin, listener, viewmodel

My listeners to changes have a lifetime and in order not to keep them in memory, I think I need to add a method, for example, `removeItemChangeListener` and call it, for example, in the `onClear` method of the view model. As far as I know, the `onClear` method is overridden as `onCreate` for the activity. Also, it seems to me that i need to convert the listener type to an interface.

MyItemsRepository.kt

```
interface MyItemsRepository {
    val items: List<ItemModel>

    fun setFavorite(itemModel: ItemModel, isFavorite: Boolean)

    fun addItemChangeListener(listener: () -> Unit)
}
```

ContentViewModel.kt

```
class ContentViewModel(
    private val repository: MyItemsRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _items: MutableLiveData<List<ItemModel>> = MutableLiveData()
    val items: LiveData<List<ItemModel>>
        get() = _items

    var isFavorite: Boolean = false

    init {
        repository.addItemChangeListener {
            getItems()
        }
    }

    fun changeFavoriteState(item: ItemModel, favorite: Boolean) {
        repository.setFavorite(item, favorite)
    }

    fun getItems() {
        _items.value = if (isFavorite) {
            repository.items.filter { it.isFavorite }
        } else {
            repository.items
        }
    }

    class Factory : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
        override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
            return ContentViewModel(MyItemsRepositoryImpl.getInstance()) as T
        }
    }
}
```

I need your help writing the code. I mentally understand how to do it, but I don't know how to write it. I would be very grateful for a written example with an explanation.

Comment: I'm confused with your implementation, why are you using `interface` & listeners. Can't you just achieve whatever you want by creating a repository class and considering it as a local data source and work with it? If you're following any tutorial, maybe mention its link in the post. Seems like you're increasing complexity for such a small architecture.

Comment: And maybe explain your use-case, what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @ParagPawar I am answering your question about a local data source. The fact is, I was given the task to create what you see in my code and I am only now working on correcting any comments. I understand that my management has arranged everything and therefore I only need to do what I wrote above. It is not necessary to rewrite the listener type, probably, these are just my guesses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try calling the method `removeItemChangeListener` the same way you're calling `setFavorite`, Just call it from the `onCleared` method of a ViewModel

```
class ContentViewModel(
    private val repository: MyItemsRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    ...

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        repository.removeItemChangeListener()
    }

}
```

And in your repository it would be something like this:

```
override fun removeItemChangeListener() {
    listeners.clear()
}
```

You cannot really do something like this: `listeners.remove(listener)` because how are you going to pass the listener from ViewModel to repository anyway?

Add the `removeItemChangeListener` method in the interface `MyItemsRepository`

```
interface MyItemsRepository {
    
    ...

    fun removeItemChangeListener()
}
```

Again, haven't really tested it, but it should work.

**EDIT:**

Different approach:

```
class ContentViewModel(
    private val repository: MyItemsRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    var listener = {
        getItems()
    }

    init{
        repository.addItemChangeListener {
            listener
        }
    }

    ...

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        repository.removeItemChangeListener(listener)
    }

}
```

And in your repository it would be something like this:

```
override fun removeItemChangeListener(listener: () -> Unit) {
    listeners.remove(listener)
}
```

Add the `removeItemChangeListener` method in the interface `MyItemsRepository`

```
interface MyItemsRepository {
    
    ...

    fun removeItemChangeListener(listener: () -> Unit)
}
```

I'm not really sure if this will work. Try it out and let me know.

Comment: When an attempt is made to call the removeItemChangeListener () function in the view model, the error "Unresolved reference: removeItemChangeListener" appears.

Comment: Check the method `removeItemChangeListener()` is correct, maybe check spellings, syntax. Or just copy-paste, the code I've written

Comment: No, it won't work, understood the problem. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: The Android Studio proposes: Create abstract function 'MyItemsRepository.removeItemChangeListener'

Comment: Edited the answer please try it now

Comment: Hey, Parag, Is it possible to make another implementation using this comment? "use an interface instead of a lambda, and inherit a viewModel from it by analogy with a click listener and a fragment, or you must store the object of this lambda and pass it to addItemChangeListener and remove it to removeItemChangeListener."

Comment: I don't really understand that comment, and without the context, it doesn't make much sense. But you can do something mentioned in the last part of the comment. Create variable with the code in your `init` function in ViewModel. and use that variable which is an object of the lamda and pass it to `addItemChangeListener ` & `removeItemChangeListener`. It's just a guess, cannot really help more without more context and knowing what you want to achieve there.

Comment: I understand you but i don't how to explain what they want from me. The only mistake they were told was to remove a specific listener from the list, and not clear it completely.

Comment: And if it doesn't bother you too much, could you show a visual implementation of your comment on working with the last part of my comment.

Comment: I edited the answer, added a different approach at the bottom, see if that works

Comment: The application started, but now when you click on the "favorite (❤)" button, the selected item is not added to the Favorites tab.

Comment: I cannot be really sure without testing it out, can't do without the full source code. Maybe you should give it more thoughts, and if that doesn't work out, show your seniors what you achieved yet, and tell them to help you out.

Comment: I showed it to my superiors and received the following comments:
1)why not private?
2)the name is too abstract, in some cases it is possible to do so, but it is better to name it more specifically.
3)you created this listener, and you delete it in onClear, why don't you sign it?

Comment: By the way, I figured out the favorite button. I replaced this code init { repository.addItemChangeListener { listener } } to this code init { repository.addItemChangeListener { getItems() } }

Comment: I corrected everything according to the comments, fixed what did not work, now everything is fine. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It would look just like your `addItemChangeListener` function, except it should call `remove` instead of `add`. Not sure which part of the concept you are unsure about. Defining it as an interface is optional. An interface would possibly help communicate the purpose of the listener better but wouldn’t change the functionality. If you do that, you’ll probably want to define it as a `fun interface` because interfaces are more fun if you can use lambdas to represent them.

That all said, if you’re open to coroutines, it would be easier for your repo to expose a Flow. Then if the ViewModel subscribes to the Flow, it will automatically unsubscribe when it goes out of scope.